# Creating graphical marker/point on Geotools map in Java?

Tags: point, geotools

I'm writing a program that tracks the International Space Station, and plots its current position on a geotools map.

I currently have a geotools map that pops up, and I have the current location of the ISS that updates every second in another class:

```
public void doIt() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/coastlines_z8.shp");
    System.out.println(url);
    File file;
    file = new File(url.toURI());

    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

    MapContent map = new MapContent();
    map.setTitle("map");

    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
    map.addLayer(layer);

    createPoint();
    JMapFrame.showMap(map);
}
```

This seems like it should be simple, but I've been scouring the internet for the past day and I can't find a definitive answer as to how to go about doing this. I've looked into SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder, but I'm unsure how to implement it.

Additionally, once I get the point drawn, how do I ensure that it is updated every second?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [style which describes your icon/graphic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73235/point-symbology-in-sld-file) and a Layer that contains a [point which describes where the space station](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190674/geotools-new-points-now-drawn-on-the-map) is.

Then to animate that you look at [GEOTOOLS - Animations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228876/geotools-animations)